# Length of linearly independent list is less than or equal to length of spanning list

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

This is the proof of the theorem given in Sheldon Axler's *Linear Algebra done right*:

[Proof of the theorem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1TK7.png)

The Linear Dependence lemma is:

[Linear Dependence Lemma](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGRjz.png)

In the proof you can see that in each step, one $u$ is added to the list of spanning vectors at the expense of one $w$, removed according to linear dependence lemma.

At the end,

> After step $m$, we have removed all the $u$'s and the process stops. At each step, as
> we add a $u$ to $B$, the Linear Dependence Lemma implies that there is some $w$
> to remove. Thus there are at least as many $w$’s as $u$’s.

**Here is my question:** How can you guarantee that some $w$'s will remain in the spanning list $B$ waiting to be removed by linear dependence lemma (note that linear dependence lemma can only remove $w$'s, not $u$'s) till you are done with the $m^{th}$ step? Doesn't the proof already assume that the *number of linearly independent vectors* is less *the number of spanning vectors*?

Comment: If there weren’t a $w$ to remove, you would have a dependence relationship among the $u$’s, but the $u$’s are independent, so this is not possible.

Comment: @MichaelBurr  Its OK if the spanning list becomes linearly independent, the process stops there. My question is, why does it have to be at the $m^{th}$ step, wait till all the $u$'s are in the spanning list, why can't all the $w$'s be gone even before all the $u$'s are in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a slight modification of the argument that might help you in understanding Axler’s.

Since the span of a list does not depend on the ordering, we can reorder lists in any way we like.

I’ll show that if we have replaced $k$ vectors in the spanning list with the first $k$ vectors in the linearly independent list and $k<m$, we’re able to replace one more vector.

The case in which $m=0$ is trivial, so we can assume $m>0$. Up to a reordering of the spanning list, we have a spanning list
$$
(u_1,\dots,u_k,w_{k+1},\dots,w_n)
$$
and therefore $u_{k+1}=a_1u_1+\dots+a_ku_k+a_{k+1}w_{k+1}+\dots+a_nw_n$ for some scalars $a_1,\dots,a_n$. Note that one among $a_{k+1},\dots,a_n$ is nonzero, otherwise we’d get a contradiction. Up to a further reordering, we may assume $a_{k+1}\ne0$ and therefore in the spanning list
$$
(u_1,\dots,u_k,u_{k+1},w_{k+1},\dots,w_n)
$$
we can remove $w_{k+1}$ to get the spanning list
$$
(u_1,\dots,u_k,u_{k+1},w_{k+2},\dots,w_n)
$$

Objection: how do we know that we still have a $w$-vector available? Let’s see. May we have $k<m$ and have exhausted the $w$-vectors? No. This would mean that $(u_1,\dots,u_k)$ is spanning and so $u_{k+1}$ would be a linear combination of $u_1,\dots,u_k$: contradiction.

Comment: If I have understood it properly, this proof of yours explains the process of adding one $u$ and removing a $w$ from the spanning list, the *steps* in the theorem. I have understood that part. But as you will see in a comment above,  my question is a bit different:  Can you get in all the $u$'s without extinguishing all the $w$'s in the list? If you see the proof, the author simply assumes that all the $u$'s can be inserted, and there will be $w$'s sufficient to do so. Why does the process have to go on for $m$-steps, why can't it end before that?

Comment: @Anu3082 I added a final remark.

Comment: Seems right! Shouldn't the author have written this down somewhere instead of just assuming we can go to the $m^{th}$ step (without using up all the $w$'s from the spanning list) by which step, all $u$'s are in the spanning list? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sure, the author assumes that we can carry on the process up to the $m^{th}$ step, but doesn't seem to provide an explanation why we wouldn't run out of $w$'s by that step (which is a possibility). As given by @egreg, here is why all $w$'s won't be deleted by the $k^{th}$ step, $k < m$.

Suppose all $w$'s are gone by the $k^{th}$ step, we will have $\{ u_k, u_{k-1}, u_{k-2}, \cdots ,u_{1}\}$ in the spanning list, whereas $u_{k+1}, \cdots u_{m}$ are left back in list containing the linearly independent vectors.

But $\{ u_k, u_{k-1}, u_{k-2}, \cdots ,u_{1}\}$ spanning vector space $V$ means that the remaining linearly independent vectors are expressible as their linear combinations, *which is contradiction to the fact that those vectors are linearly independent*.

Therefore so long as there are $u$'s left in list $B$, there would be $w$'s waiting to be dropped from the spanning list. Because *linear dependence lemma* replaces one $w$ by one $u$ in list $A$, length of list of spanning vectors $\geq$ length of list of linear independent vectors.